# How to let a Mercurial repository automatically push to another when it receives a new changeset?

Tags: mercurial, automation, push, commit

I have three Mercurial repositories `repo`, `repoA` and `repoB`.  I'd like the following happen

some edits in `repoA`
   commit to `repoA`
   push manually to `repo`
   `repo` updates and pushes to `repoB` **automatically** as soon as it receives commits from `repoA`

Comment: `push` may fail. How would you handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [Mercurial hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook)?

For instance:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg up; hg push repoB
```

If you're on Windows, the hook command-line would be instead `hg up & hg push repoB`.

(note that for more complex stuff, you can instead just call a Bash/Cmd script instead of one-liner like this)